# Html2Canvas Text in input or textarea not capturing text

Tags: javascript, text, textarea, html2canvas

I am trying to capture div with image and textarea text(user input) in it. but it show me only image which is in div and showing blank text which is inside the same div. Cannot able to figure out how to capture text with latest version.
Thank you for any help!

I am trying to capture that on blur. when user input and focus out/blur it should capture text.

Here is code i am trying :

```
 $(document).on('blur', '.image-text', function(event) {
    html2canvas($('.class').find('.div-class-to-take-snapshot').then(function(canvas) {
    $('.class').find('.div-class-to-set-snapshot').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    });
```

it capturing blank textarea. but showing image.

Comment: Thank you for consideration. It was fixed.

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1347

Answer (score 0):

I checked that Github link provided but did not find the solution. However, I checked my CSS file and it happened that I gave a styling like this to my images:

```
 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

When I removed this styling, I started seeing the text on the capture.